# WebDriver wait.until using the arrow function throws exception when false

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

This works if true but fails when it hits false. Is there any way to make this work while it is true?

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> colorIsInThreshold = arg0 -> {
            try {
                if(isTrue){
                    Assert.assertTrue(colorPixel > threshold);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    Assert.assertTrue(colorPixel < threshold);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        wait.until(colorIsInThreshold);
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: In question itself you are saying it is working while it is true and asking same question???

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code:

**so if you read the documentation of asserttrue:**

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals(boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)

you can see that asserttrue throws an error and not an exception.

In java, **Exception** and **Error** are subclasses of the parent class called Throwable.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptions-in-java/

So in your code you are trying to catch an exception, and thus your code never reaches the catch block. So instead, replace exception with throwable :

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> colorIsInThreshold = arg0 -> {
            try {
                if(isTrue){
                    Assert.assertTrue(colorPixel > threshold);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    Assert.assertTrue(colorPixel < threshold);
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        wait.until(colorIsInThreshold);
```

**Tips:**

if you are returning true or false, then why are you asserting it? use below code and you will get what you need.

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> colorIsInThreshold = arg0 -> {
               return isTrue ? colorPixel > threshold : colorPixel < threshold;
        };
        wait.until(colorIsInThreshold);
```

Also , what should be the behavior when pixel is equal to threshold?